# Arg of $(1-i\sqrt{3})^6$. Did I do it right?

Tags: complex-numbers

Did I do it right?

$(1-i\sqrt{3})^6$

module = $\sqrt{1+3}=2$

$(1-i\sqrt{3})^6=2^6\cdot(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)^6$ $\implies$ Arg = $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: How did you conclude that $\pi/3$ is the answer in the last step? What is the argument of $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you did, but it is wrong as $(1-\sqrt{3}\cdot i)^6=\boldsymbol{64}$ (Therefore the $\text{Arg}$ is $0$).

To solve this, let $z=(1-\sqrt{3}i)^6$. We'll turn $1-\sqrt{3}\cdot i$ into its polar form.

So, $|1-\sqrt{3}\cdot i|=\sqrt{1^2+(\sqrt{3})^2}=2$ like you've said. Also, $\text{Arg}(1-\sqrt{3}\cdot i)=-\dfrac{\pi}{3}$

Finally, $z=(2\text{cis}(-\dfrac{\pi}{3}))^6=2^6\text{cis}(-2\pi)=2^6\text{cis}(\boldsymbol{0})=2^6=64$

Comment: Yeah but I am looking for the argument of that complex number.

Comment: Please refer to the edited version (note: the argument of a real number is always $0$)

Comment: Are you saying that you do not know what the argument of 64 is?

Answer (score 0):

The argument of $1- i\sqrt{3}$ is $\arctan(-\sqrt{3})= -\frac{\pi}{3}$  So the argment of $(1-i\sqrt{3})^6$ is  $6\times-\frac{\pi}{3}= -2\pi$ which is equivalent to 0.

(Edited to correct negative sign, thanks to Ripi2.)

Comment: Yoiu mean $arctan(-\sqrt 3)$, right?

Answer (score 0):

$Re^{i\theta} =(1-i\sqrt{3})^6$

$\Rightarrow $$Re^{i\theta}=2^6(\frac{1} {2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^6$

$\Rightarrow $$Re^{i\theta}= 2^6 (e^{\frac{-i\pi}{3}}) ^{6}$

$\Rightarrow $$ 
Re^{i\theta}= 2^6e^{-i2\pi} $

$\Rightarrow$$ R=2^6$, $\theta=-2\pi+2k\pi$

$K=1$

So:

$R=64 $ and $ \theta=0$